# sql statement help

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table which called people, and I have there 2 columns, name and age

How can i select the names with age above 15 for example ?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "age above 15" I suppose that you actually mean "age 15 and above"?

Comment: but we don't know what he means. we can only read his question. so " age > 15" is correct.

Comment: @r3zn1k: It does answer the question as it's written, but that doesn't mean that it's of any use. If we only ever answered question as they were written, the only possible answers for a lot of them would be simply "yes" or "no", which although correct is almost totally useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT name FROM people WHERE age > 15
```

Comment: That will get the people with an age of 16 and above. You want to use >= 15 to get the people with an age of 15 and above.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, age
FROM people
WHERE age >= 15
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select name from people where age > 15
```